# R concate 2 numeric columns with big numbers

Tags: r, concatenation

I want to concate 2 columns with numbers and get as result a number.
Example: 
First column: 123456
Second column: 78910
Desired Result: 12345678910

```
test<-matrix(
  c(328897771052600448,4124523780886268),
  nrow=1,
  ncol=2
)

test<-data.frame(test)

str(test)
```

Both columns are numeric

```
colnames(test)<-c("post_visid_high","post_visid_low")

test_2<-transform(test,visit_id=as.numeric(paste0(post_visid_high,post_visid_low)))
```

Problem:
My concated result gives: 3.288977710526004289528e+33
I dont understand why I get this (incorrect??) number.

When I exlcude "as.numeric" I get the right result:

```
    test_2<-transform(test,visit_id=paste0(post_visid_high,post_visid_low))
test_2
```

But its converted into "factor":

```
str(test_2)
```

Comment: The answer given by `as.numeric()` is correct. Its only that the digits printed are less are less than the number. `print(test_2,digits=20)` can reveal what is stored. although this still does not reveal everything. Try using smaller numbers and you will see that `as.numeric` gives the correct values

Comment: But how its possible, that the numbers differ? The single number 328897771052600448 becomes converted to 328897771052600428 in the combined number (please see the last two cipher "28" instead "48). Why "28"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These numbers are to large to be stored exactly as `numeric`. You can either store them as string by specifying `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`:

```
test_2<-transform(test,visit_id=paste0(post_visid_high,post_visid_low), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
test_2
#>   post_visid_high post_visid_low                           visit_id
#> 1    3.288978e+17   4.124524e+15 3288977710526004484124523780886268
str(test_2)
#> 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ post_visid_high: num 3.29e+17
#>  $ post_visid_low : num 4.12e+15
#>  $ visit_id       : chr "3288977710526004484124523780886268"
```

Or you use something like `gmp` to process arbitrary sized integers:

```
library(gmp)
test_3 <- test
test_3$visit_id <- as.bigz(paste0(test_3$post_visid_high, test_3$post_visid_low))
test_3
#>   post_visid_high post_visid_low                           visit_id
#> 1    3.288978e+17   4.124524e+15 3288977710526004484124523780886268
str(test_3)
#> 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ post_visid_high: num 3.29e+17
#>  $ post_visid_low : num 4.12e+15
#>  $ visit_id       : 'bigz' raw 3288977710526004484124523780886268
```